# Exception is thrown, Page is called, but object is null

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am new to SpringMVC and I am running into a strange error.
On purpose I've created a "NullPointerException" to test my ErrorPage handling and Exception handling.

Now I have this Method which requests the mapping for the NullPointerException

```
@ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
public ModelAndView handleCustomException(NullPointerException ex) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("ErrorPage");
    model.addObject("status", "NullPointerException: " + ex.getMessage());

    return model;

}
```

The method is called, I know this because I can see the actual page, but for ex.getMessage() there is always "null" (and the object is null).

Can someone explain to me why and how I can solve this?

Comment: That's because a `NullPointerException` thrown by `Object a = null; a.doSomething();` doesn't have a message. Try by explicitely throwing a NPE with a message.

Comment: did you create an instance of NullPointerException? or your message might be null...

Comment: `throw new NullPointerException`

Comment: I've created a nullpointer exception the way Tunaki did it  NullPointerException thrown by Object a = null; a.doSomething();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness:

The exception was thrown but as @Tunaki said, an exception thrown with

```
Object a = null; a.doSomething();
```

has no message. So I created a new NullPointerException with a message and throw it manually. Problem solved!